# How to add EthereumWallet's wallet to geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp

i am struggling to add my EthereumWallet wallet to geth.

I should run a command like this:

```
get account import <keyfile>
```

I downloaded a file from the EthereumWallet website, and I ran this command. I got an error like this:

```
Fatal: Failed to load the private key: encoding/hex: invalid byte: U+007B '{'
```

I think that I am doing something completely wrong.

Comment: could you explain what is EthereumWallet in your opinion?